# Refactoring the code in order to avoid assigning an Object to null

Tags: java, object, null, sonarqube

I have made a simple method in Java and I have a major error telling me that "Assigning an Object to null is a code smell. Consider refactoring.". Thus I should consider refactoring my code, but I am not sure I can find a way to re-write my sample of code differently.

Here is the code :

```
public static Key buildKey(TypeA a, TypeB b) {
        Date myDate = new JavaDateUtcIsoStringDateConverter().from(String.valueOf(a.getDate));
        Integer DateInt = new JavaDateUtcAvroIntDateConverter().to(myDate);

        TypeNb nb = b.getById(a.getNbId());

        Key.Builder builder = Key.newBuilder();

        builder.setOr(a.getOr());
        builder.setDest(a.getDest());
        builder.setDateInt(DateInt);
        builder.setLine(nb.getLine());
        builder.setIdNb(nb.getIdNb());
        builder.setOpS(nb.getOps() != null && String.valueOf(nb.getOps()).length() > 0 ? String.valueOf(nb.getOps()) : null);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

The main error comes from the line `builder.setOpS(nb.getOps() != null && String.valueOf(nb.getOps()).length() > 0 ? String.valueOf(nb.getOps()) : null);`

How can I refactor this simple condition in order to avoid using `null` ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Might be more suitable for code review, as there seems to be no actual error in the strictest sense. Why however would assignment of `null` be seen as a 'code smell'?

Comment: That's what I am asking to myself to be honest. I do not know how to refactor.

Comment: i don't see the problem, but since you also check the string length, you could just set it to "" . But i think theres nothing wrong with setting it to null

Comment: You probably shouldn't even be calling `builder.setOpS()` if the parameter is `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like:

```
if(nb.getOps() != null && String.valueOf(nb.getOps()).length() > 0) {
    builder.setOpS(String.valueOf(nb.getOps());
}
```

... assuming you don't need to explicitly set the builder's value as null if nb.getOps() is empty.

Comment: I think that's perfect for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If u don't want to use null pointers you should take a look at optional in Java 8 or GUAVA.

[explanation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Answer (score 0):

In builder pattern , avoid setting anything explicitly to null. If you want to set something to null, don't call the setter.

Also, keep it simple. You can use Apache commons-lang's [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) utility class for String not-null & not-empty

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nb.getOps())) {
builder.setOpS(String.valueOf(nb.getOps());
}
```